# Can't get any jquery to fire in wordpress admin - no errors showing

Tags: jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using wordpress for my cms and I am using this great plugin [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) to add some custom fields into my admin.

In my admin, everything is working great and I am using the latest wordpress 3.8

OK so I simply want to add some jquery to interact with a select dropdown in my post admin. This select dropdown is generated by the [ACF plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/).

[ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/actions/acfinputadmin_head/) give you a simple hook to add scripts and css into the head of the admin panel. [See hook documentation here](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/actions/acfinputadmin_head/).

So here it is...

```
// WEATHER DATA ICON
function hrc_weather_type_field_icon()
{
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">

        body { display: none !important }   

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){



    })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('acf/input/admin_head', 'hrc_weather_type_field_icon');
```

The above works fine. If I look at the source I can see the above markup appear in my `<head>`

OK but if I do this...

```
// WEATHER DATA ICON
function hrc_weather_type_field_icon()
{
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">



    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){

        $('body').empty();

    })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('acf/input/admin_head', 'hrc_weather_type_field_icon');
```

I can still see this mark up in my source `<head>`, but the script is not firing!!!

And there are no errors or warnings in the consol, and everything that requires scripts on the page are working as normal.

Obviously I don't want my `<body>` to be emptied, I'm just testing basic API's to actually get the scripts to fire.

The script below is the script I originally tried, but I thought it was a problem with the script itself, but then after realising there cant actually be a problem with it, I started testing other basic jquery API's like `.hide`, `.remove`, etc and nothing actually fires!!!

```
// WEATHER DATA ICON
function hrc_weather_type_field_icon()
{
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">

        /* ... */

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){

        $("#acf-field-weather_data_weather").on('change', 'select', function() {
            alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
        });

    })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('acf/input/admin_head', 'hrc_weather_type_field_icon');
```

If any has any insight to why this could be possibly happening, I would be so thankful as it's driving me crazy :-P

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created the scope but there is doc ready handler is missing:

```
(function($){
  $(function(){  //<------this is the doc ready
     $('body').empty();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You have really really helped. Can't believe that caught me out like that. Thank you!!!

Comment: Well this is SO and we do it like that...`:)`

Answer (score 1):

Try using jQuery's [noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(document).ready(function($) {

    j("#acf-field-weather_data_weather").on('change', 'select', function() {
        alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, i tested it first and I got scripts to work, but Jai's answer works to and I think maybe I was getting confused with the functon doc ready not actually being the doc ready. Thanks anyway for your help